# MVC - Calling an external Web service and displaying it in a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC. The task I have at hand is to contact a web service call one of its methods and display it in a view. I have started by creating a new MVC2 appln. in VS2010.  Here is my index.aspx(default page) view:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
<p>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Create Soap Request</legend>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateSoapRequestResult","CreateSoapRequest",
                        new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divSoapRequestDetails" }))
{
    <div id="divSoapRequestDetails"></div>
    <ol>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("Method")
            @Html.TextBox("txtMethodName")
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("Username")
            @Html.TextBox("txtUsername")
        </li>
        <li>
            @Html.Label("Password")
            @Html.TextBox("txtPassword")
        </li>
    </ol>
<button>Generate Request</button>
}   
</fieldset>
</p>
</asp:Content>
```

But I am at wits end trying to figure out how to pass data around. I assume I need to pass this on to a controller(or to a model) which will then create the soap request, call the service method and get the response. Please correct me if I am wrong. I then have to present it in another view(preferably).

Answer (score 1):

You should keep things simple:

```
#1)  Create a model that contains ALL the data elements for your view, this is called a ViewModel.  This model goes in the "Models" folder in your MVC App.
#2)  Call the Web Service  from your controller, if you're fluent in c# this wont be a problem.
#3)  Change your view to work with the model.  use the @model attribute in the view.
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();   // <-- obviously this is named as an example
    WebService.Service = ws = new WebService.Service();
    string name = ws.GetName();

    vm.Name = name;
    return View("Index", vm);

}
```

In your view:

```
@model ViewModel
. . . 
rest of html/razor.
```

Comment: I actually want to pass data from the form in the view. In reality I am not calling a web service using a service reference like you do typically. I am writing a request response code to get the xml and have put it in a helper class. I thought getting the data from the form into a controller would be the first step. Then use my helper class to get the response,populate my model and display it in the view. Is this not the right approach.

Comment: it depends, if you are doing MVC then your model should be handled in the controller not the form.

Comment: Sorry, I think I got the wordings wrong. I meant transferring form data to the controller. Like a login form. Say I want to build a login page. How would I get the username and password to a controller?

Comment: maybe this is a MVC 2.0 thing but the ASP.NET MVC I use has access to all HttpContext and all that it contains.